# RSpec Active Record Scope

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I want to write a scope that requires that the start date of products be less than today.  I wrote the following in rspec

```
it "Should not be found with a start date in the future" do
   @product.start_date = Date.tomorrow
   @product.save

   Product.active.find(@product.id).should == nil
end
```

That test fails, obviously.  Then I wrote the scope-

```
scope :active, where('start_date <= ?', Date.today)
```

Then I rerun the spec and it fails with-

```
2) Product Should not be found with a start date in the future
 Failure/Error: Product.active.find(@product.id).should_not == true
 Couldn't find Product with ID=1 [WHERE (start_date <= '2010-12-20')]
 # ./spec/models/product_spec.rb:168:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I cannot figure out how to get this code to pass.  I do not want the product to be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the error: *"Couldn't find Product with ID=1"*, the scope is actually working. Problem is in your test, `find` raises an exception as usual because no record has been found. You either have to use `find_by_id` or assert the exception with rspec.

Comment: yup, errtheblog has lots of cheat sheets. One more thing, check factory_girl if you are not using it, you'll write better testing code.